# Trouble in floating elements

Tags: html, css

Please have a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dbrH9/1/). As you can see i have `float: left` on `label` element, i was expecting that `Country4` should start from new line according to the maximum height of the above elements, but it didn't how can i achieve following result without adjusting `margin-top` and `margin-left` (that is not flexible way of doing it as **there can be country5, coutry6 later on**):

*Note: It is not certain that there will be always three labels per row it can be 2 or 3 or 4. `So clear:both` after specific number of elements won't work in this case.*

[image]

Here is the simple code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            label {
                float: left;
            }
            dt {
                font-weight: bold;
                color: green;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form style="width: 460px">
            <fieldset>
                <label>
                    <dt>Country1</dt>
                        <dd>United States</dd>
                        <dd>United States</dd>
                </label>
                <label>
                    <dt>Country2</dt>
                        <dd>United States</dd>
                        <dd>United States</dd>
                        <dd>United States</dd>
                        <dd>United States</dd>
                        <dd>United States</dd>
                </label>
                <label>
                    <dt>Country3</dt>
                        <dd>United States</dd>
                </label>
                <label>
                    <dt>Country4</dt>
                        <dd>United States</dd>
                        <dd>United States</dd>
                        <dd>United States</dd>
                        <dd>United States</dd>
                        <dd>United States</dd>
                </label>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please include valid code to reproduce the problem **in the question itself.**

Comment: will you like to use jquery for this??

Comment: @Zword i was hoping to get some simple css solution. If there is no way then jquery is fine :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `float` you may want to use `display:inline-block`:

```
label {
  width:130px;
  vertical-align:top;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

And the demo **http://jsfiddle.net/dbrH9/6/**

Comment: I was finding a solution using JQuery.But you did it with simple CSS. +1

Answer (score 0):

To a label you want to put into a new line, apply this:

```
<label style="clear:both">
```

Comment: Not necessary country4 is the last element. There can be country5 country6 later on.

Comment: It will work... Only put this to each first element of a line

Comment: If i apply your method on all `label`, it will stacked them vertically as there is `float: left` on label.

Comment: Not all! only first element of each line so to label1, label4, label7...Either this, or group it in div's, or use <br/>...

Comment: No that is not certain. If the definition of element is bigger then there will be either two/row or three/row.